# stop PerformRequestsWithTarget during process, when low memory warning received

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

On `ViewDidAppear`,

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(generatePdf) withObject:nil];`

is called.  This generates a large PDF as soon as the view is loaded.  In order to factor in low memory issues, can I stop this process when once its started?  Using

`[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(generatePdf) object:nil];`

does not work,  presumably because its already been called as soon as the view has appeared.  I want to stop this process if app receives `didReceiveMemoryWarning` so im looking for a solution that will just stop it completely in my `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


 LogCmd();
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if (self.pdfData == nil) {



    // Generate PDF

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(generatePdf) withObject:nil];
   }
}

 ....some code


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {



[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(generatePdf) object:nil];


}
```

Comment: you can have a variable and can change it's value and depending upon that value you can return from the `generatePdf` method.

Comment: Do you mean making a bool/flag, check its value and if running cancel the perform selector?   How do I return from the `generatePDF`?

Comment: no I mean if you are doing some task in `generatePdf` and in this you can check bool value whether to return or continue working on pdf

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for reply. Not sure I get it, ive added more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop a running method but you can return from it.

e.g.

```
- (BOOL)generatePdf{
    // some task

    if (memoryWarning){
        return NO;
    }

    // some Task

    if (memoryWarning){
        return NO;
    }

    //some Task

    if (memoryWarning){
        return NO;
    }

    //some Task

    //PDF has been successfully generated
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, that makes sense, thank you for your help, plus 1

Comment: Mmm, tasty concurrency issues.

Comment: @tc. yep concurrency issues are there. :)